# AttributeError: 'ItemIterator' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy

```
import numpy as np 

import pandas as pd 

import tweepy as tw

from tqdm import tqdm
```

```
access_token="[my access token]"
access_token_secret="[my access toke secret key]"
consumer_api_key = '[my consumer key]'
consumer_api_secret = '[my consumer secret key]'
auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_api_key, consumer_api_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

```
search_words = "#BTC -filter:retweets" 
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
              q=search_words,
              lang="en",
              fromDate='2021-07-08',
              toDate='2021-08-08').items(100)
tweets_copy = []
for tweet_df in tqdm(tweets):
    tweets_copy.append(tweets)
```

```
tweets_df = pd.DataFrame()
for tweet in tqdm(tweets_copy):
    hashtags = []
    try:
        for hashtag in tweet.entities["hashtags"]:
            hashtags.append(hashtag["text"])
    except:
        pass
    tweets_df = tweets_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'name': tweet.user.screen_name, 
                                               'user_location': tweet.user.location,
                                               'user_description': tweet.user.description,
                                               'user_created': tweet.user.created_at,
                                               'user_followers': tweet.user.followers_count,
                                               'user_friends': tweet.user.friends_count,
                                               'user_favourites': tweet.user.favourites_count,
                                               'user_verified': tweet.user.verified,
                                               'date': tweet.created_at,
                                               'text': tweet.text, 
                                               'hashtags': [hashtags if hashtags else None],
                                               'source': tweet.source,
                                               'is_retweet': tweet.retweeted}, index=[0]))
```

**im getting this error when i run the last code**

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-5751369fbbcf> in <module>
      8 except:
      9     pass
---> 10 tweets_df = tweets_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'name': tweet.user.screen_name, 
     11                                                'user_location': tweet.user.location,
     12                                                'user_description': tweet.user.description,

AttributeError: 'ItemIterator' object has no attribute 'user'
```

**anyone know why?
I checked twitters documentation and ItemIterator 'tweet' does have the attribute 'user'**

Comment: Did you mean `for tweet_df in tqdm(tweets): tweets_copy.append(tweet_df)`? Seems odd to append the whole `tweets` over and over.

Comment: @BatWannaBe i just tried this, I'm still getting the same error